# CSS 'float: right;' issues

Tags: html, css, css-float

I currently have a simple header set up in HTML, and am using CSS to style it.  I have created multiple styles: '#header' and '#header #right'.  When I use 'float: right;' for the second style I mentioned, it moves the text down almost completely under the header.

**Code:**

index.html:

```html
<html>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
<link href='main.css' type='text/css' rel=Stylesheet>
<head>
<title>FriendSub</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='header'>
<font size='+3'>FriendSub &nbsp; &nbsp;</font>
<a href='index.php'>Home</a> | 
<a href=''>Subscribers</a> |
<a href=''>Subscriptions</a>
<div id='right'> 
  <p><a href=''>Log in</a> | <a href='register.php'>Register</a></p></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#header {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #093;
    border-top-left-radius: 18;
    border-top-right-radius: 18;
    width: 96%;
    height: 58px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    color: #FFF;    
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: #000 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}

#header a {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: #000 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}

#header a:hover {
    color: #CCC;
}

#header #right {
    float: right;
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #093;
}

#content {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    width: 1000;
    height: 58px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 600;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 18;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 18;
    line-height: 1%;
}
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aKtep/

Comment: It may help to add a screen shot of what you are seeing and the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding a `<div style='clear:both'></div>` right after you close `#right` and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution (assuming I understand your desired result) is to rearrange the elements so the item you want to float to the right is the first in header.  Floated elements are removed from the normal flow of the document, and often are pushed to the next line unless they have enough space.  However, if the floated element comes first, subsequent elements will arrange themselves around it.  See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuHQc/).

Comment: I recommend you read up on floated elements if you have time, however, as my explanation is oversimplifying things.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the p tag from around the Login/Register link, modify the #header #right to include a padding-top:10px; You're also using too many divs when you don't really need to (divitus)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a width of units for your container `#header` that will accommodate all of its content.

All I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x9zDc/) was change `#header` width from `96%` to `960px`

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm not 100% sure on what you're asking but it sounds like your normal header is pushing the right header down below it. From what I can see, it may have to do with your header container having a width of 96%. Then the #right #header has a width of pixels and the original header container might not have enough room left for that many pixels. Try changing the width of `#header #right` to a %

A word of advice, don't use ID's so much. You are creating very high specificity that can be a pain for you later on.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, you should use `clear: float` after the **#right** segment.

The reason for this is that [the clear property](https://kolosek.com/css-clear-float/) is related directly to [the float property](https://kolosek.com/css-float/).  **It specifies if an element should be next to the floated elements or if it should move below them.** This property applies to both **floated and non-floated** elements.